# Нужна помощь. Не понимаю как исправить проблему. Почему на 3-ем и 4-ом вызове функции массив из значений после 2-го прохода превращается в undefined?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Напишите функцию, которая принимает первым параметром объект, вторым - массив из цепочки свойств, по которому нужно пройти, чтобы получить значение.

Если какое-то из свойств не найдено - функция возвращает undefined.

```js
function optionalChaining(obj, chain) {
    if (Object.keys(obj) == chain[0] && chain.length == 1) {
        return obj[chain[0]]
    } else if (chain.length != 1) {
        return optionalChaining(obj[chain[0]], chain.slice(1))
    } else
        return undefined
}

const obj = { a: { b: { c: { d: 'Привет!' } } } }
const obj2 = { a: { b: { name: 'Pavel' } } }

console.log(optionalChaining(obj2, ["a", "b", "name"])) // Pavel
console.log(optionalChaining(obj, ["a", "b", "c", "name"])) // undefined
console.log(optionalChaining(obj, ["z", "c", "d"])) // undefined
console.log(optionalChaining(obj2, ["z", "c", "d"])) // undefined
```

Comment: Как написано, так и работает ) Вы проверяете, что ключ есть в объекте, если это не так, то возвращаете **undefined.** В 3-м и 4м вызове вы передаете первым **z**, а данный ключ отсутствует в объекте и вываливаетесь в ваш `else`

Comment: Не пишите полностью вопрос в заголовке, а выделите только главную проблему. После 2го прохода где? В теле функции? "массив из значений" - obj или obj2 undefined? Опишите возникщую проблему так, чтоб она была понятна: что, когда, где.

Comment: Из странного, что по вашему делает этот код `Object.keys(obj) == chain[0]`?

Comment: @SwaD нет, он не возвращал **undefined**, в последних двух вызовах функции свойства **z** не было в `obj` и свойство конвертировалось в ```undefined```, а проверки на ```undefined``` не было и выкидывало с ошибкой ```TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object```
@XelaNimed Хорошо, про описание учту теперь, спасибо. Проблему описал чуть выше в комментарии.
@AlexeyTen сравнивает массив со строкой, да, это изначально неправильно было, я просто не был ещё знаком с ```.hasOwnProperty```.

Проблема решилась заменой ```keys``` на ```.hasOwnProperty``` проверкой на **undefined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.keys(obj) == chain[0]` неподходящее сравнение, правильнее `obj.hasOwnProperty(chain[0])`.
Не было проверки на `undefined` с возвратом его же самого.
Правильный код:

```
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(chain[0]) && chain.length == 1) {
        return obj[chain[0]]
    }
    else if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(chain[0])) {
        return undefined
    }
    else (chain.length != 1)
    return optionalChaining(obj[chain[0]], chain.slice(1))
}
```